# Problem with accordion in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, accordion

I have a list of strings that I loop throu, and then add them in a Accordion. When I've added all of them I want the last item to expand. The code looks like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ivDialogList.Count; i++)
        {
            AccordionItem ai = new AccordionItem();
            ai.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
            ai.HorizontalContentAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
            ai.Content = ivDialogList[i].Message;
            ai.Header = ivDialogList[i].PostType + " " + ivDialogList[i].User + " " + ivDialogList[i].PostDate;

            if (i == ivDialogList.Count - 1)
                ai.IsSelected = true;

            content.Items.Add(ai);

        }
```

This is working fine, but as soon as I click on any of the other accordion items or close the last one, I get an out of range exception. Does any body have another way of doing this or know the reason why I get the exception and can help.
Thanks

Comment: Which line gives the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the question. I think the problem was somewhere in the loop, and probably specific for my code. What I did was that I moved the:

```
if (i == ivDialogList.Count - 1)
            ai.IsSelected = true;
```

part in the loop out, so it would be set after the loop is done, like this:

```
((AccordionItem)content.Items[ivDialogList.Count - 1]).IsSelected = true;
```

And that made it work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me using "Lore Ipsum.." text, the toolkit Accordion and a bunch of AccordionItems - the problem must be in some of your code that you are not showing here. Can you post a stacktrace and the XAML?